# Is there any way to run blender 2.80 add-ons on Blender 2.79

Tags: add-on

I tried to run a Blender 2.80 addon script on blender 2.79. But it is not working. Is there any way to run it?

Comment: Blender 2.80 has brought many changes to the python API, so many commands or functions of Blender 2.79 will not work on Blender 2.80.

To make a 2.79 addon work on 2.80 it needs to be modified to reflect those changes by the creator or by any other people of the community who is willing to spend the time on it. I suggest you to search for the update version on the internet, and if it's not there, ask on this or other forums for the updated version. Many other people will probably benefit from it as well

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The [Python API has changed](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API) between the two versions and therefore add-ons for Blender 2.79 won't run in Blender 2.80 and the other way around.

You would have to modify the code of the add-on to let it run in Blender 2.79.